# Return DataFrame from within python function rather than list using pandas' pd.read_sql_query

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlite, dataframe

I am struggling to understand why this returns a list containing a DataFrame rather than only the DataFrame. Is there something wrong with the code or a way to return only the DataFrame?  It works as expected if not placed within a function.

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

def get_tbl_info(db ='MyDatabase', table ='Measurements'):

        database = "/Users/Mary/Documents/Database/{DB}.db"..format(DB=db)

        conn = sqlite3.connect(database)

        tbl_info_command = "PRAGMA TABLE_INFO({table});".format(table=table)
        result_all = pd.read_sql_query(tbl_info_command,conn)
        print(type(result_all))
        return [result_all]



out = get_tbl_info()
print(type(out))
```

gives:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'list'>
```

Comment: Because you're returning it as a list via the square brackets: `return [result_all]`.  Try just `return result_all`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when you enclose a variable with brackets `[ ]`,  Python understands it as **"ok put this variable inside a list"**. Just replace the `return` of your function with:

```
return result_all
```

This should work properly, or actually your function could just return your dataframe directly

```
return pd.read_sql_query(tbl_info_command,conn)
```